# flash light is not working when camera is on

Tags: android, android-camera2, flashlight

I'm creating barcode reading application using google vision and it consists a flash on/off function also. i was able to implement flash using "CameraManager" like in the following code due to the "Camera" is now deprecated.but when camera screen is on, flash light is not working.when camera is freeze(when barcode is detected i'm stoping the camerasource), flash light is working. but i want to flash light on/off with out regarding the camera view is on or stop.i need this get done without using the deprecated APIs.can some one tell me how i can get solved this problem. thanks in advance.

```
 private void setupBarcode(){
    cameraPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
    txtResult = findViewById(R.id.txtResult);

    barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
            .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.ALL_FORMATS)
            .build();
    cameraSource = new CameraSource
            .Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
            .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
            .build();
    //Add Event
    cameraPreview.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Request permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ScanActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, RequestCameraPermissionID);
                return;
            }
            try {
                cameraSource.start(cameraPreview.getHolder());
                txtResult.setText("");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            cameraSource.stop();

        }
    });

    barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
        @Override
        public void release() {

        }

        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            final SparseArray<Barcode> qrcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
            if (qrcodes.size() != 0) {

                txtResult.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        okButton.setEnabled(true);
                        txtResult.setText(qrcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
                        cameraSource.stop();

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

private void flashLightOn() {
    CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

    try {
        String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
        cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the open source 'CameraSource.java' file from goole vision library in your project.
[Get file from here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java#L534)

And then use the following code:

```
public void switchFlashLight(boolean status) {
    cameraSource.setFlashMode(status ? Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH : Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
}
```